# Using Javascript animation library VS creating dynamically <style> tags to be injected in the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, velocity

We are creating a complex single page application, which allow an user to create animations on some widgets, example a widget button could be animated from left to right and change its opacity during x second. Also another widget can influence the animation of another, making a transaction animation on top of another.

Animations can be defined by an user and triggered by JavaScript application in a quite complex way. Animations could be edited in several combinations and date for animations is created using OOP approach.
Animation could be reverted, paused, played.

Regarding the animation technology we are evaluating currently two options:

01 - Using CSS Transition, creating necessary CSS classes dynamically and injecting the  tags in the header of the page. The animations will be added to the dom also switching classes will be handled.

02 - Using a JS library like Velocity.js or Greensock, animating the DOM accordingly using JS so only using inline style.

03 - Web Animation API (and CSS Animation), we have tried this approach but we found some specific limitation.

I would like your feedback:

Approach 01:

- Is manageable in JS in term of programmatic control.
- Is it possible to edit dynamically a property in a  tag without causing flickering and not using complex regex?
- Are you aware of any issue with adding  tags dynamically in the Header, like flickering.
- Have you found CSS Transition lack of performance when multiple animation are running in parallels.
- Do you know some project using this approach?
- What about control of animation, like reverse, stop, pause.

Approach 02:

- Do you think is this approach generally more manageable by JS?
- Any CONS on this which would make chose approach 01 instead?
- What about control of animation?

Any feedback is very welcome.

Some useful article I read

https://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation

Comment: Please let me know if question is more suitable for another stack exchange site. Like programmers. Thanks guys.

Comment: Also this is a very complex question which answers will be influenced by experience and personal preferences, I'd like to comment something. CSS transitions and animations are limited. It will be way easier to create a javascript controlled timeline with default alternation of any element in the scope of the animation (parent selection). Also CSS transitions can behave different across browsers.

Comment: see [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have complex animation that can be manipulated mid-execution, do it with JS and not CSS. What library you will be using depends on you.

Comment: I agree with this answer. CSS Transition is fine for simple animations as also mentioned in w3 documentation https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/ , sincerly, with minimal control on the animation using JS I believe CSS Transition is not a manageable option in OP case.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with using a JS library is that you will then have to debug both hardware animations and JS animations. On top of that you would also have to learn all the quirks within those libraries. In the last 3 years i've found CSS animations and transitions to be simpler and thus better due to the fact that debugging is simpler. Debugging is key when it comes to animations on the web.

With that said there are a plethora of ready-to-use helpers (or libraries if you will) that makes it much simpler to work with more complex CSS animations and transitions. If i were you i would start with checking out the existing libraries and see if any of them meet your requirements.

Here is two small libaries using CSS animations:
https://github.com/FelixRilling/microAnimate
https://github.com/daniel-lundin/snabbt.js

Many of these would support you saving user animations in the way you describe.

Example from microAnimate:

```
var myAdvancedAnimation = new Anim(
  document.getElementById("square"), {
    "0%": [
      ["width", "200px"],
      ["color", "transparent"]
    ],
    "20%": [
      ["width", "100px"],
      ["color", "#fff"],
      function() {
        console.log("callback 2");
      }
    ],
    "100%": [
      ["width", "60px"],
      ["color", "red"],
      function() {
        console.log("callback 3");
      }
    ]
  }, {
    duration: 2000,
    ticklength: 30,
    ease: true,
    retainEndState: true,
    loop: false
  }
);
```

As you see it would be trivial to let the user save a specific animation since it's just objects and arrays that could be saved to users localStorage or a central database. It would also make it simple to have animationType `A` influence animationType `B`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, (I did not make a down vote). Regarding your points, JS libraries usually handle hardware acceleration and animations  with JS by default (look Velocity.js), all libraries you have mentioned using underlying JS engine to make an animation and they do not use pure CSS transition (basically they are JavaScript Libraries with a CSS-like animation syntax). For my understanding CSS Transition cannot be applied inline, and a class must be created in the header, which could be more difficult to manage. Could you confirm that? Thanks for your time on this :)

Comment: No, the libaries i mention uses JS to add CSS-based animations, Velocity.js uses JS to add JS-based animations. No, a class doesn't need to be created in the header. Basically the CSS animation libaries are used to not have to do all such things.

Comment: I understand that mentioned JS libraries add CSS animations, but the property of the INLINE CSS is always generated dynamically by JS and do not include Transition). They do no use PURE CSS Transition. I believe that for my understanding you cannot even add CSS Transition directly inline on the DOM and should be included in the header if dynamically generated, or imperatively in the CSS style and using JS to switch classed like this https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/ what do you think?

Comment: @Tommie so do you basically suggest to use a JS library for the job?

Comment: @Radex Yes, for complex animations. But one really do need to understand the difference between a micro-library for adding CSS-based animations and a full-blown library for adding JS animations.

Comment: @GibboK You can add transition properties inline if you want. See ie http://cdn.rawgit.com/tommiehansen/lightRange/master/test.html and click the arrows on the dates to change month. The technique used just updates an inline transform value and since it has a transition defined within the CSS it animates the calendar months. They do use pure CSS animations, the logic is just for adding/removing properties basically.

Comment: @Tommie thanks for link, are we talking about the same think :)? In the example you are showing me CSS3 2D Transforms with a translation like `style="transform: translateX(-500%);"` I could not find CSS Transition, instead I am talking about CSS3 Transitions added inline, otherwise must be added in the header :) http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: @GibboK You could not find CSS-transition since it isn't in the head of the document but is definied in the CSS-file. It was an answer to your "defined in the head". It seems you would need to actually try some of the libraries and understand how they work. With something like snabbt.js you don't have to add anything except the library itself and the animation logic with js. Just like with any small helper or library for CSS-animations, check something like: http://codepen.io/tommiehansen/pen/bpXNPr?editors=0010

Comment: @Tommie I understand your point, as I need to generated the value for CSS-transition dynamically on JS, I will definitely follow your advice and try one of the the mentioned JS libraries. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: @GibboK Good luck!